# Chart With Production Summary for each work-Shift C# .NET WindowsForm Client Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts, controls

its my first post here, im not very good in english but i will try.

i need to make a graph like this one

[The chart that im trying to recreate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsSZo.png)

based on a datatable filled by a SQL query that is structured like this:

[Result of The query that i need to chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuVvv.png)

now i have come up with this idea that is working quite well, but i am struggling with some aspect of it:

[What i have come up with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNA5q.png)

i need to show only the x value that are present in the query result, but since that they are datetime value when i add to the graph every point the x axes of the chart show me a linear time scale of every time of the day not only the point that i add to the chart.
that is the main problem,

the other problem is that i need, when there are too much value showed, to be able to scroll horizontally the chart to see all the other values using the mouse scrolling wheel.

i thank y'all guys in advance hope that i have wrote all the information, in any case i can give you guys more if you need them

tysm

i now attach all the code insterested in the topic:
(The designer)

```
namespace GRAPHICOBJECTS
{
    partial class GRAFTREND
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Variabile di progettazione necessaria.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Pulire le risorse in uso.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">ha valore true se le risorse gestite devono essere eliminate, false in caso contrario.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Codice generato da Progettazione componenti

        /// <summary> 
        /// Metodo necessario per il supporto della finestra di progettazione. Non modificare 
        /// il contenuto del metodo con l'editor di codice.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea chartArea1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
            this.CHART = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.CHART)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // CHART
            // 
            this.CHART.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(175)))), ((int)(((byte)(175)))), ((int)(((byte)(175)))));
            chartArea1.AxisX.Enabled = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.AxisEnabled.True;
            chartArea1.AxisX.Interval = 1D;
            chartArea1.AxisX.IntervalAutoMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.IntervalAutoMode.VariableCount;
            chartArea1.AxisX.IntervalType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Hours;
            chartArea1.AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = false;
            chartArea1.AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 90;
            chartArea1.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd/MM HH:mm";
            chartArea1.AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 0D;
            chartArea1.AxisX.LabelStyle.IntervalType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Hours;
            chartArea1.AxisX2.Interval = 1D;
            chartArea1.AxisX2.IntervalAutoMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.IntervalAutoMode.VariableCount;
            chartArea1.AxisX2.IntervalType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Hours;
            chartArea1.AxisX2.IsLabelAutoFit = false;
            chartArea1.AxisX2.LabelStyle.Angle = 90;
            chartArea1.AxisX2.LabelStyle.Format = "dd/MM HH:mm";
            chartArea1.AxisX2.LabelStyle.Interval = 0D;
            chartArea1.AxisX2.LabelStyle.IntervalType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Hours;
            chartArea1.Name = "ChartArea1";
            this.CHART.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);
            this.CHART.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1, 0);
            this.CHART.Name = "CHART";
            this.CHART.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No;
            series1.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
            series1.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
            series1.IsVisibleInLegend = false;
            series1.Name = "S2";
            series1.XValueType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.DateTime;
            series2.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
            series2.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
            series2.IsVisibleInLegend = false;
            series2.Name = "S1";
            series2.XValueType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.DateTime;
            this.CHART.Series.Add(series1);
            this.CHART.Series.Add(series2);
            this.CHART.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1012, 350);
            this.CHART.TabIndex = 1;
            this.CHART.Text = "CHART";
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 352);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(58, 43);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 2;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // GRAFTREND
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.CHART);
            this.Name = "GRAFTREND";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1015, 398);
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.UserControl2_Load);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.CHART)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart CHART;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    }
}
```

(now my Sql request Query with the use of my Drawchart function)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "GetStatisticalData_ShiftGraph";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataStartSH", "2021-09-01 06:00:00.000");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataEndSH", "2021-09-02 06:00:00.000");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecipeName", "TEST");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LineN", 1);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    NRecord = da.Fill(dt);
    GraphicFunctions.DrawChart(this.CHART, dt, "TimeShift", "Rejected", Color.Yellow, "TimeShift", "Good", Color.LightGreen);

    this.CHART.Series["S1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
    this.CHART.Series["S2"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
    this.CHART.DataManipulator.InsertEmptyPoints(1, IntervalType.Days, "S1");
    this.CHART.DataManipulator.InsertEmptyPoints(1, IntervalType.Days, "S2");
}
```

(and now my function)

```
public static void DrawChart(Chart ObjChart,DataTable DTable, string xColumnS1, string yColumnS1,Color ColorS1, string xColumnS2, string yColumnS2, Color ColorS2)
{
    double PointsCount;
    try
    {
        ObjChart.DataSource = DTable;
        ObjChart.Series["S1"].XValueMember = xColumnS1;
        ObjChart.Series["S1"].YValueMembers = yColumnS1;
        ObjChart.Series["S2"].Enabled = true;
        ObjChart.Series["S2"].XValueMember = xColumnS2;
        ObjChart.Series["S2"].YValueMembers = yColumnS2;
        ObjChart.DataBind();
        PointsCount = ObjChart.Series["S1"].Points.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i <= PointsCount - 1; i++) ObjChart.Series["S1"].Points[i].Color = ColorS1;
        PointsCount = ObjChart.Series["S2"].Points.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i <= PointsCount - 1; i++) ObjChart.Series["S2"].Points[i].Color = ColorS2;
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: We need to see the relevant code that sets up the chart and fills in the data.

Comment: ok ok now i have added all the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved that, in order to have one X value point for every data column i needed to index all value from the two series with the setting (for each series):

```
series10.IsXValueIndexed = true;
```

more info about that on Microsoft help:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.series.isxvalueindexed?view=netframework-4.8